# ORACLE inserts with CLOB column (more than 4000 characters)

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

first of all sorry for my english.

I am trying to insert approximately 15000 rows, the problem is that there is a column of type CLOB that can have more than 4000 characters giving the error ORA-01704, I know how to insert one by one like this: TO_CLOB (string) || TO_CLOB (string) and it works, but I have approximately 1000 cases where it happens and I don't want to do it manually, what way can you think of to insert them?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to insert 15000 rows to a single column by concatenating them. If you are saying you want to insert 15000 rows knowing that 1000 records would fail for sure, you can create a anonymous pl/sql block to loop through and insert and handle exception to skip the bad ones. Please provide more details for someone to help you better.

Comment: hi, no, i am trying to insert more than 4000 characters in a clob column

Comment: I have 15000 insert staments to inserts in the database, 
of which approximately 1000 have the problem that the CLOB type column exceeds 4000, and I know how to insert one by one but I want to know if I can do something for all cases where there are more than 4000

Comment: Have you tried with sql loader? How do you retrieve the data for your insert? Do you have only the insert statements?

Comment: export the information from navicat, from a BD sql server and I will insert it into ORACLE

Comment: insert into table (id,column_clob) values ('1', '4000 CHARACTERS') to , insert into table (id,column_clob) values ('1', TO_CLOB('2000 CHARACTERS' ) || TO_CLOB('2000 CHARACTERS' ) )

Comment: but I have 1000 records like this and I don't want to do it manually :(

Comment: What I suggested was doing something like [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader)

Comment: Luis, where is your clob data coming from? Is each CLOB per row being populated from say..a file on disk?

Comment: I have the inserts in a text file so that's why I would need a solution other than doing it one by one

Answer (score 0):

i think you're trying something like that:

```html
insert into values('your clob data');
```

in this case you are using sql literal size which length 4000 bytes.
11g and below,the limit is 4000 bytes.
But if you use script like that :

```html
   declare
        l_clob varchar2(32767);
   begin
    ...
        insert into values(l_clob );
    ...
   end
```

it means you are using pl sql literal string which has 32k.

Comment: sql VARCHAR2 limit in 12c and higher is now 32k...version of oracle wasn't mentioned here, but still

Comment: Yeah, that works but I have 1000 records like this and I don't want to do this for each row

Comment: @thatjeffsmith good point .So Could you show your code @Luis?